Refresh repositories list and link applications to repositories
The following Ubuntu repository has been broken for some time: http://ftp.rezopole.net/ubuntu jammy Release  Indeed, the folder is missing.
An initial question is: How to find the name of a corresponding (working) Ubuntu repository that can replace that one?
Now, to fix this issue the first idea is to disable the corresponding repository to be able to complete a full upgrade without facing errors. It raises two concerns:

If you disable repos, how to rebuild a list of repos that will contain the ones needed to update all the applications installed on your system?
For any application, how to find repos that are linked to it to ensure that updates can be operated?

If you do not fix this issue, you may end up with a system running applications that are never updated...

If you want to find a list of Ubuntu mirrors you can view https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors  where I think you were after https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+mirror/ftp.rezopole.net-release which you'll note it reports as BROKEN.  Switch to another source.

As far as I'm aware of you can't do either of those two things automatically. Even though I'd like to be proven wrong.
The tracking of what you have and from where to fetch it is done through repos, and excluding those tracked packages all you're left with is binaries on your system that may or may not have a working repo providing them, somehwere on the internet.
No tool that I'm aware of will be able to "magically" map your "orphaned" (as in "currently not provided by a working repo") package to a possible alternate repository, let alone to map an executable installed, say, using a script, to a repository that provides a relative package, if that's what you're asking.
Manual housekeeping is certailny possible by searching the "orphaned" / untracked packages on Launchpad and that's what I would advise you do.
